# Determine how many variables needed so that sum is bigger than 8000

Tags: statistics

I want to determine how many instances of a random variable I need, so that the probability that the sum of them is bigger than 8000 is over 95%.

My statistics lectures have been a few years ago, so I cannot find the right approach. I think it's related to the sampling size determination, however I could not apply the formulas to this problem.

Let $X$ have the distribution:
$P(X=1)=0.53925,$
$P(X=2)=0.03572,$
$P(X=3)=0.00039,$
$P(X=4)=0.05596,$
$P(X=5)=0.00004,$
$P(X=6)=0.00002,$
$P(X=7)=0.00008,$
$P(X=8)=0.36853.$

I want to determine the smallest n that fullfills:
$P((\sum_{i=0}^n X)\ge 8000) \ge 0.95.$

I am happy about any kind of help.

Comment: Getting a start (using R statistical software): Copying probabilities, `p=c(0.53925, 0.03572, 0.00039, 0.05596, 0.00004, 0.00002, 0.00008, 0.36853)`. Checking that they add to 1, `sum(p)` returns 0.99999. Computing population mean `x=1:8; sum(x*p)` returns 3.78482. Then pop var is 10.8477, and pop standard deviation is 3.293584. Do you know or can you find formulas for mean $\mu,$ variance $\sigma^2,$ and standard deviation $\sigma ?$ Next is to find mean $E(S_n)$ and variance $Var(X_n)$ of $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ using @RossMillikan's answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment and @RossMillikan's answer helped me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to use the normal approximation.  For the sum of random variables, the mean of the sum is the sum of the means.  The variance of the sum is the variance of the means.  Use that variance to compute a standard deviation.

Comment: Isn't the normal approximation only usable for the Binomial distribution? Which is not the case for the distribution of X?

Comment: No, it is usable for any sum of random variables.  It is called the central limit theorem.  How quickly the distribution of the sum converges to normality varies with the distribution, but the binomial is one of the worst.  With $8000$ variables you should be in good shape.

Comment: Thanks! Using the central limit theorem was the right apporach.